# brew and node commands not found

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm very new to this. Back in January 2018 when I installed Homebrew and Nodejs, commands were found. I uninstalled and reinstalled both yesterday along with a mac OSX update. Now neither brew nor node commands are found.

> user$ node
>   -bash: node: command not found
>
> user$ brew doctor
>   -bash: brew: command not found

I've checked through Finder that they are both installed. 
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: They are in `/usr/local/bin`, so set your PATH like this `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` Also, run `xcode-select --install` if you have upgraded macOS.

Comment: Thank you very much! export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH works.